# splitting text into character and numeric

Tags: r, stringr, readr

Could someone help me split this string:

```
string <- "Rolling in the deep    $15.25"
```

I'm trying to get two outputs out of this:

```
1) Rolling in the Deep  # character
2) 15.25                # numeric value
```

I know how to do this in excel but a bit lost with R

Comment: Are you trying to extract numeric value(s)?

Comment: No I want both, character and Value separately

Comment: It's easy to extract data in this particular case, but for a general case, we would need more data. Please provide more if you see fit. For instance, can we expect a numeric values as the last entry in the string? Is it always denoted in dollars?

Comment: I have updated my `string` variable - apologies I missed in the first time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `strsplit` will do the trick. The solution will be as:

```
string <- "Rolling in the deep    $15.25"

strsplit(string, "\\s+\\$")
                    ^   ^___ find a $ (escaped with \\ because $ means end of word)
                     \______ find 1 or more whitespaces
# Result
#"Rolling in the deep" "15.25"

strsplit(string, "\\s+\\$")[[1]][1]
#[1] "Rolling in the deep"

strsplit(string, "\\s+\\$")[[1]][2]
#[1] "15.25"
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the regex used here.

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Thank you so much. I had planned to edit it per your advise and it got on hold for many hours.

Answer (score 1):

As long as the right hand side is always preceded by a dollar sign, you will need to "escape" the dollar sign. Try this:

```
# you will need stringr, which you could load alone but the tidyverse is amazing
library(tidyverse)
string <- "Rolling in the deep    $15.25"
str_split_fixed(string, "\\$", n = 2)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's how you can extract the information using only regular expressions:

```
x <- c("Rolling in the deep    $15.25",
       "Apetite for destruction    $20.00",
       "Piece of mind    $19")

rgx <- "^(.*)\\s{2,}(\\$.*)$"
data.frame(album = trimws(gsub(rgx, "\\1", x)),
           price = trimws(gsub(rgx, "\\2", x))
           )

                    album  price
1     Rolling in the deep $15.25
2 Apetite for destruction $20.00
3           Piece of mind    $19
```